# Can't Link Storage Firebase images, to Cloud Firestore correctly

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I dont understand why I am not able to link and send the URL to the cloud firestore collection document
the image is picked up correctly in Storage but cant get URL in cloud firestore db
here is my code:

```
  bool isLoading = false;
  var firebaseUser =  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;


  Future uploadImage(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
    Reference firebaseStorageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$fileName');
    UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile);
    TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
    if (taskSnapshot == null) {
      final String downloadUrl =
      await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(firebaseUser.uid)
          .collection("influncerUser")
          .add({"imageUrl": downloadUrl,});
      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, why to use `if (taskSnapshot == null)` ? If the taskSnapshot is null you can't fetch the download url, so delete it.

Second, prefer use `onComplete` instead of .whenComplete(() => null)

```
Future uploadImage(BuildContext context) async {
String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
Reference firebaseStorageRef =
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$fileName');
UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile);

// use onComplete to await when the doc has been pushed.
TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;

final String downloadUrl = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(firebaseUser.uid)
    .collection("influncerUser")
    .add({"imageUrl": downloadUrl,});
setState(() => isLoading = true);
```

}

Comment: onComplete seems deprectated and I got a redline below, the only options available is whenComplete.

Comment: neither in this way It adds the URL to the collection in cloud firestore. I got this error as well:
Failed assertion: line 129 pos 12: 'isValidDocumentPath(documentPath)': a document path must point to a valid document.

Comment: I didn't know that onComplete was deprecated. It seems the user's path is incorrect, is the user document stored in a collection or at the root of your Firestore ?

Comment: E/flutter ( 3791): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart': Failed assertion: line 129 pos 12: 'isValidDocumentPath(documentPath)': a document path must point to a valid document.
E/flutter ( 3791): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
E/flutter ( 3791): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
E/flutter ( 3791): #2      FirebaseFirestore.doc (package:cloud_firestore/src/firestore.dart:129:12)

Comment: I removed whenCompelte I leave it as is: TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask; but still nothing

Comment: this does not work, you need to use whenComplete to wait. But the problem is not here, it is when you add the url. You should use FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('yourCollection').doc() if your user is stored in a collection with the other users.